# How to add callback functions in JSON driven UI (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, callback

I am working on JSON driven UI Layout in React
Following is an example

```
{
  component: "card",
  children: [
    {
      component: "img",
      src:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2877188/pexels-photo-2877188.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
    },
    {
      component: "body",
      children: [
        {
          component: "title",
          children: "This is a title"
        },
        {
          component: "subtitle",
          children: "This is the subtitle"
        },
        {
          component: "button",
          children: "Click Me!",
          onClickCFunction: "SOME CALLBACK FUNCTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I am rendering the above JSON in react using React.CreateElemene() and in the button **I want to define a callback function where when user clicks on the button it will run that even**t !

Is this possible and how can I achieve this, can somebody help me out there ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check on that and revert ! So I can write a function in a eval wrapper ?

Comment: If you store the function as a string you can pass that into eval - though this can be a bit of a security risk (which is noted in the mozilla docs).

Comment: Considering it has risk, then is there any alternate for the same ?

Comment: Without knowing your business requirements it's a little tough to say for certain, but generally yes there is probably another architecture that doesn't require storing functions in JSON. That said, the risk essentially stems from where those functions are originating from. If the function can in any way be altered/added by a malicious party then it's definitely a risk.

However, if the functions in the JSON are hardcoded in, then you may be able to just store some kind of identifier that allows you to reference the corresponding function instead of storing the function itself.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the insights ! And what is that another architecture ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could structure something like this - without knowing more about your application though it would be tough to really describe anything much more specific than what I added in that last comment... If you'd like to chat separately or send more specifics on the purpose/role that this data serves in your app that might help

Comment: How can we connect ?

Comment: Hey, sorry - I tried to respond last night but SO went in to maintenance mode on me.

[Here's a slack invite](https://www.saltify.io/en/halophilic/aa07e9f7db19ea0397195651ea245b8604a7a8cc82fb0e32d72e4b381c4b7cba/fd389b385fef4c2390885d0bc95de0f3adb178075ac6220e716467a30d637ab4) if you want connect there?

Comment: Hello, Invite link is broken actually !

Comment: @lazyCoder - Here's a [fresh one](https://www.saltify.io/en/halophilic/5e13afb334731ade3a4911702bbc4b9f2573da5f23462acda52782b62def1713/c934617ea591244a01e3303f4651999a5df7686ea1d4f747c55cbf492178d0ad). Sorry, I set that last one to expire after only an hour.